# Prove that if $A$ is not invertible, $\lambda=0$ is one of the eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I only know how to prove the reverse. Anyone give any ideas for this proof?

Answer (score 5):

$$\det(A)=0 \implies \det(A-0Ι)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

When $A$ isn't invertible, there is a nonzero vector in the nullspace of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is not invertible then $AX=O$ has non-trivial solution. i.e., $AX=0X$ for some non-zero $X.$ This implies $0$ is eigenvalue of $A.$

Answer (score 2):

To put it more fundamentally: a linear operator isn't invertible when it fails to be one-to-one and/or it fails to be onto, because a linear operator which is one-to-one and onto is invertible (actually, proving that the inverse function is linear takes a small amount of work, but it's true).

If $A$ is not one-to-one, then the nullspace is nontrivial, as others have pointed out. It is due to the rank-nullity theorem that $A$ is one-to-one if and only if it is onto, and therefore failing to be onto implies that it fails to be one-to-one.

Note that this claim is false if $A$ is a linear operator on an infinite-dimensional vector space, so you must use finite-dimensionality somehow, e.g., using the determinant or rank-nullity.